# How to Share Multiple Documents in Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

How to share multiple documents from document Library?

Comment: Create document set instead of folder; that's how it supposed to be.

Answer (score 5):

The Best way is to Create a New Folder and then add all documents into it and after that create a user group (If you haven't) and then assign the group permissions to that group for that folder.

Comment: Or any way? Any other customization by any REST API code or tool to Share Multiple files to particular user?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no direct way to share Multiple Documents at one click.But one Workaround is.

- Create a new Folder( maybe give it name as Shared)
- Move all the files into that folder
- Share that folder with other users

ShareWith option in the Ribbon will share the complete Document library to the user.

Comment: By Clicking on "Shared With" option ( 2nd from the Right in the Ribbon) it will share with document library not with particular document share functionality

Comment: u are right, i just did a test and found it. see the updated answer.